# Replacement mains cable for Elehot Hair Clipper ET-H121 (Strange D shaped 2pin socket)

Tags: mains

I'm looking for a replacment power cable for an Elehot hair trimmer with an odd D shaped socket as shown in the attachment. I've spent hours googling without success. Any help gratefully received. .[image]

Comment: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete* - I understand that visiting the barbers is a bit off-limit with covid but requests for product recommendations are still closed-down (excess hair or not).

Comment: Dumpster diving in the recycling depot might yield quicker results. Although once desperate on a coldt night I fashioned an epoxy shell in WD40 with Molex pins to make one for an electric blanket

Comment: It looks like it's basically a C8, but with a flat files at one end, perhaps for polarisation, or maybe just to be a PITA for generic alternatives. Offer a C8 up to it, and if the pin spacing is right, you could try shaving a bit of plastic off.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need a cable with a Polarised IEC 320 C7 socket on the end, though you'd need to confirm the dimensions to be certain.

[image]

Image from https://www.cablestogo.com/learning/connector-guides/power#!c7-polarized